# Can I legally photocopy a whole book for personal use?

Tags: copyright, spain

**Question:** Is it legal for someone to photocopy a whole book, in their own home, for personal, individual, non-profit use?

**More context:** I can take whatever printed materials I want to an exam. I want to heavily annotate my book (allowed by the university) but I don't want to ruin the original book. I thought of photocopying it and annotating the copy. In case it's relevant, I would destroy the copy after the exam.

Comment: I am fairly sure this is a dupe...

Comment: I have found a bunch of these questions, but all in the context of the US, none which were general or about Spain

Comment: I dont know where people get the idea that personal use somehow makes a copyright breach less illegal. Seems a rather widespread copyright myth.

Comment: @NeilMeyer In Spain, which is the target of the question, personal use seems to be an actual exception to the law (as a layman): https://www.osborneclarke.com/insights/the-private-copying-exception-under-spanish-law